# "unused arguments" error with lavaan::cfa

Tags: r

I do confirmatory factor analysis. I set up syntax specifying which items load onto each factor

```
theory_syn_eq <- "
ZAV: Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4, Z5, Z6 #Závažnost
DOP: D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6 #Dopadení
PPZ: Pr1, Pr2, Pr3, Pr4, Pr5, Pr6 #Problémproživot
ROD: R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6 #Rodiče
PRA: P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6 #Přátele
SP: S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6 #Školapráce
"
```

But I can not feed the syntax in to have variances and covariances automatically added by this code:

```
theory_syn <- cfa(text = theory_syn_eq, reference.indicators = FALSE)
#Error in cfa(text = theory_syn_eq, reference.indicators = FALSE) :  
#  unused arguments (text = theory_syn_eq, reference.indicators = FALSE)
```

I tried install cfa and lavaan package, but still does not work.

Comment: What does "*does not work*" mean please? Do you get errors?

Comment: Errors: 
 `Error in cfa(text = theory_syn_eq, reference.indicators = FALSE) : 
  unused arguments (text = theory_syn_eq, reference.indicators = FALSE)`

Comment: actually it seems `lavaan` doesn't have the argument `reference.indicators` in `cfa` -- are you looking at an old guide perhaps? In fact, seems like it is the package `sem` that has this argument. See `?sem::cfa`

Comment: `sem` package works. Cheers mate.

Comment: Just FYI, you can try `blavaan` which is the bayesian version.